# CamelCase completion for PHP

Tags: aptana, caml, aptana3

Is anybody know if the camelcase completion can be activated in aptana studio 3 for php ? 
I explain my self :
In example : framework classes Test_Class_Sample_One, Test_Class_Sample_Two, etc..
I type :

```
new TCS
```

and i want Aptana to show a completion list with :

```
Test_Class_Sample_One
Test_Class_Sample_Two
etc...
```

Is it possible ??
Thanks
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not available at this time.
You can open a ticket at http://aptana.com/r/apbugs and we'll try to take care of this as soon as we can.

Thanks!